# Have a problem with if else choose to login.activity or register.activity

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio

currently,i had done the login and register activity in android stdio,but when i try it will keep go with Else statement `in protected void onPostExecute(String result)`

i already try to get the result.equals value from the dialog that displayed such as LoginSuccessful and RegisterSuccessful but also didnt work.

So that if else part going some problem,what should i do for it?

i had tried change it in many way but still dont work.

```
import XXXXXXXXXX;(skip import thing)



public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;

    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Intent intent;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url="http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:XX/login.php";
        String register_url="http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:XX/register.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(type.equals("register")){
            try {
                String name = params[1];
                String username = params[2];
                String password = params[3];
                String email = params[4];
                String phonenum = params[5];
                String age = params[6];
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("phonenum","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phonenum,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(age,"UTF-8")+"&";
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(result.equals("LoginSuccessful")){

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Userprofile.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(result.equals("RegisterSuccessful")){

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Below is the problem i faced:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if(result.equals("LoginSuccessful")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Userprofile.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            if(result.equals("RegisterSuccessful")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

if not mistaken i think the problem is the value error in `if(result.equals("LoginSuccessful"))` or how can i know the result value(not from dialog box)

Comment: that is not a "problem", it's a bit of code. What exactly is your code? my first guess, you need an else before "if (result.equals("RegisterSuccessful"))" as well.
At this point, if your result is "LoginSuccessful", it will also run the else block

Comment: @Stultuske if i remove if else and just put one of them such as  Intent intent = new Intent(context, Userprofile.class) or Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class) it will work find,but when i put if else it will keep go to else.the result values i get from the alertdialog that displayed before put in if else statement.

Comment: I haven't said anything about removing if else, just adding an else.

Comment: so if not mistaken i think is if(result.equals("LoginSuccessful")) and if(result.equals("RegisterSuccessful")) goes somthing wrong?

Comment: @Stultuske sry,i cant understand,can you told abit clearly?thanks

Comment: You haven't mentioned what problem you are having. what is going wrong with the code you posted above?

Comment: @Stultuske yes,i think is the second part i mention in post that face problem,but i try to change the result.equals(value) but didnot work also.

Comment: @Stultuske keep going else,becuse if i login successful should go the another.activity.

Comment: you state that you always get the else but you fail to mention in which case this is. have you read my first comment? in that, I mention what I think is your problem

Comment: What do these tags mean? All I see is android code.

Comment: @Stultuske i had read your comment,but i am trying to explain my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

As you've suggested, the problem is most likely with the actual value of `result` in the onPostExecute method.

You can log the value of `result` with `Log.e(TAG,result);` and then view the logs in the Logcat tab in Android Studio. The onPostExecute method would then become:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(result.equals("LoginSuccessful")){

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Userprofile.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(result.equals("RegisterSuccessful")){

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Registration failed: " + result);
        }
    }
```